# Code generation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, code-generation, code-templates, eclipse-m2t-jet

What is the most useful code generation tool in eclipse, velocity or [jet templates](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJET/article.html)? Anybody has experience with both of them and know the pro and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Jet, but I like Velocity very much.  I especially like the fact that it looks so much like the end product.  I think it makes things easier than something like JSP for generating HTML.

Answer (score 6):

In the **Telosys** Eclipse plugin we are using **Velocity 1.7** 
( for scaffolding and for wizards )

It works fine and it can be embedded in a plugin

To try it :
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools
For more information :
http://www.telosys.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) API in eclipse JDT.